# how to write SQL query in parameter of jasper report?

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, report

In iReport, i want to put the sql query in my parameter expression editor as following.

(!$P{securityGrading}.equals("0")) ? "SecurityGrading- " + "select description from [KRISADMIN].SecurityLevel where Level = $P{securityGrading}" : "SecurityGrading- Default to all"

But the iReport can't execute my sql query. I know it doesn't recognize my sql query since i'm using double quote but how do I get my query works in it?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem which I see is in the addition of the parameter value.

Correct way would be 
If Level Column is integer then -

(!$P{securityGrading}.equals("0")) ? "SecurityGrading- " + "select description from [KRISADMIN].SecurityLevel where Level =" + $P{securityGrading} : "SecurityGrading- Default to all"

If Level column is of type varchar

(!$P{securityGrading}.equals("0")) ? "SecurityGrading- " + "select description from [KRISADMIN].SecurityLevel where Level ='" + $P{securityGrading} +"'" : "SecurityGrading- Default to all"

You need to take care that the dynamic values supplied from the parameters in ireport need to find the legit SQL.

Hope that this helps.